# SOAP services iOS

Tags: ios, web-services, soap

I wanted to call SOAP services, saw many document's over link.
I used one of those like the BestSoaptool from github https://github.com/yillars/BestSoapToolwithafnet, but I am still lacking some where and not able to get the response.

I am using the link as -- "https://aaa.com/Customers.svc?singleWsdl" and then the method name  "xxx" but I don't get a response.

If not this can any one give me some better idea as to how should I implement this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've added sample SOAP implementation in iOS in my wordpress blog. Hope this will help you https://wordpress.com/post/bharathreddys.wordpress.com/6

Lets assume the following .wsdl url is the source URL.

```
http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL
```

Create a SOAP Envelop and SOAP Header.

```
NSMutableString * soapHeader = @"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""

        " xmlns:hom=\"http://www.webservicex.net/">"

        "<soapenv:Header/>";
```

Be remember that "xmlns:hom", text next to ":" is the word which will be used as the targetnamespace reference for the service call which will be added in SOAP body.

SOAP body will be as follows :

```
[soapHeader appendString:@"<soapenv:Body>"];

[soapHeader appendString:@"<hom:GetGeoIP>"]; // add the body parameters

[soapHeader appendString:@"<hom:IPAddress>0.0.0.1</hom:IPAddress>"];

[soapHeader appendString:@"</hom:GetGeoIP>"];

[soapHeader appendString:@"</soapenv:Body>"];

[soapHeader appendString:@"</soapenv:envelope>"];
```

Now the web service is as follows:

```
NSMutableString * requestStr = [NSMutableStringstring];

[requestStr appendString:soapHeader];

NSString * urlStr = @"http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?WSDL";

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];

NSMutableURLRequest * request = [[NSMutableURLRequestalloc] initWithURL:url];

[request setValue:@"http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

[request setValue:@"http://www.webservicex.net/" forHTTPHeaderField:@"targetNamespace"];

[request setValue:@"text/xml;charset=UTF-8"forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:requestBody];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:[NSStringstringWithFormat:@"%d",[requestBody length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

    BOOL isSuccess = YES;

    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    NSLog(@"received data---%@",response);

    if(connectionError != nil) {

        isSuccess = NO;

        NSLog(@"connection error with code %d",connectionError.code);

    }

    NSDictionary * responseDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionary];

    if([httpResponse statusCode] == 200) {

        isSuccess = YES;

     //Do something with the received dictionary.

}];
```

This is the basic platform how we can make a simple SOAP based web service calls in iOS.

Happy coding !!!!

Comment: I don't have a wordpress account, could you paste the answer here ?